# FreeBSD 10 does not boot after clean install

Tags: boot, freebsd

Latest FREEBSD 10 does not boot after clean installation.

Installed using this image: FreeBSD-10.0-RELEASE-amd64-memstick.img

Used Guided Partitioning, where I selected my only hard drive, chose Entire Disk and selected "finish". Autopartitioning looked perfectly OK: GPT, boot, ufs, swap

Installation goes OK without any error message, but after final reboot - I get no bootable device found.

I tried these command in LiveCD shell:
`gpart bootcode -b /boot/mbr ada0`
`gpart set -a active ada0`

I also tried this command
`gpart destroy -F /dev/ada0`
after which I re-installed BSD and it still does not boot.

Hard drive's SMART looks good. No bad sectors. BIOS settings are correct (UEFI is turned off).

I was able to successfully install previous version of FreeBSD using `FreeBSD-9.2-RELEASE-amd64-memstick.img` and followed exactly same steps, autopartitioning looks absolutely identical.**

I tried to install using CD version `FreeBSD-10.0-RELEASE-amd64-disc1.iso` and I get exactly same issue, BIOS won't boot it.**

Please help, I'm not sure why 10.0-RELEASE won't boot.

The same problem is experienced in FreeBSD-10.0-RELEASE-i386-disc.iso too

Comment: First, with GPT, you should use /boot/pmbr instead of /boot/mbr. Then, boot partition should contain /boot/gptboot. Try to follow instructions from gptboot(8) manpage to restore booting.

Comment: @Netch: Followed your advise and performed `gpart bootcode -b /boot/pmbr -p /boot/gptboot -i 1 ada0`, but BIOS still won't boot.

Comment: Exactly same issue here: https://forums.freebsd.org/viewtopic.php?t=44607 but I also tried replacing hard drive to an older one, and it did not work.

Comment: Try this [ZFS root install script](https://calomel.org/zfs_freebsd_root_install.html) if you don't mind using ZFS.

Comment: Same issue here. I don't get any error messages, the boot process just stops after `Verifying DMI Pool Data ...` (which comes from the BIOS or whatever, not from the OS).

Answer (score 5):

I had a similar problem and here's what I had to do on FreeBSD 10.0. Since you don't yet have an answer, here's what I did. After the install (which I did with GPT and ZFS), I opted to go to the terminal instead of rebooting. I then ran the following commands.

```
gpart set -a active /dev/ada0
gpart set -a bootme -i 1 /dev/ada0
```

'1' was the number of my boot partition from `gpart show`.

Comment: This fixed the issue after installing FreeBSD-10.2-RELEASE-amd64-memstick. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Possible stating the obvious here, but when this kind of thing happens and I don't know why, I assume it's some problem with the partition table, old geom metadata or suchlike. I just fill the drive with zeros using `dd` and worry about something else while it's happening. I can't recall this strategy failing unless the BIOS didn't want to play.

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be that the guided / automatic hard drive partitioning uses a `GPT` partitioning scheme. After a clean FreeBSD 10.0 AMD64 installation using default values everywhere (except obviously for root password, etc.), my machine wouldn't boot either.

I re-did the installation, this time partitioning the hard drive manually using an `MBR` partition scheme and the machine now boots. The installer does not provide any help here, so make sure you first create a FreeBSD partition and then create partitions (with filesystem type and mount point) within that partition. It helps to take a screenshot (using a camera :o)) or write down the automatic sizes set by the installer automatically in a previous `GPT` partitioning.

My motherboard (I believe the BIOS is the crucial bit here) is a [Gigabyte GA-EX58-UD4P](http://www.gigabyte.com/products/product-page.aspx?pid=2986) with the latest non-Beta BIOS version F13. The manual doesn't even mention GPT.